# svnkit without environment variables?

Tags: java, environment-variables, svnkit, yajsw

I use svnkit to download files from an SVN. When I run my program as a Windows service using YAJSW, the program is run as a System user, where APPDATA is set to some path in C:\Windows. svnkit is then unable to write to that directory.

As I did not find out how to run the YAJSW service as a different user with different environment variables, I would like to know whether I can use svnkit without relying on Windows environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that it is much easier to set the directory for svnkit in

```
SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(new File("D:\\temp\\"),
            user, password.toCharArray());
```

Then the value of APPDATA does not matter anymore for svnkit.